# Derivative of improper integral.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Having trouble trying to differentiate this.

$y(t)=e^{it} + \alpha\int_{t}^{\infty} sin(t-s)\frac{y(s)}{s^2} ds $

$y'(t)=ie^{it}+\alpha\frac{d}{dt}(\lim_{a\to\infty}\int_{t}^{a}sin(t-s)\frac{y(s)}{s^2}ds$)

Can I bring the derivative inside the limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking limit is not necessary, as long as integral $\int_{t}^{\infty} sin(t-s)\frac{y(s)}{s^2}ds$ exists and $ \int_{t}^{\infty} \frac{d}{dt}(sin(t-s)\frac{y(s)}{s^2} )ds$ exists.

we might need t cannot be 0. if it differentiates it at t = 0, it becomes very interesting.

$y'(t)=ie^{it}+\alpha\frac{d}{dt}(\int_{t}^{\infty}sin(t-s)\frac{y(s)}{s^2}ds)$

$= ie^{it} - \alpha (sin(t-s)\frac{y(s)}{s^2})|_{s = t} + \alpha \int_{t}^{\infty} \frac{d}{dt}(sin(t-s)\frac{y(s)}{s^2} )ds$

$=ie^{it} + \alpha \int_{t}^{\infty} cos(t -s)\frac{y(s)}{s^2} )ds$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use the identity $\sin(A\pm B) = \sin(A)\cos(B)\pm \cos(A)\sin(B)$.